# Yii Migration, Tables are not created

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii(Still Learning) I am following a book tutorial
here I did as it was written in the book created a new migrate

```
yiic migrate create create_issue_user_and_assignment_tables
```

and in safeup I wrote this query

```
$this->createTable('tbl_issue', array(
'id' => 'pk',
'name' => 'string NOT NULL',
'description' => 'text',
'project_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
'type_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
'status_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
'owner_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
'requester_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
'create_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
'create_user_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
'update_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
'update_user_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
), 'ENGINE=InnoDB');
//create the user table
$this->createTable('tbl_user', array(
'id' => 'pk',
'username' => 'string NOT NULL',
'email' => 'string NOT NULL',
'password' => 'string NOT NULL',
'last_login_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
'create_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
'create_user_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
'update_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
'update_user_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
), 'ENGINE=InnoDB');
```

and this in safeDown()

```
$this->dropTable('tbl_issue');
$this->dropTable('tbl_user');
```

then run it and got the following msg

```
D:\wamp\www\yiisite\protected>yiic migrate
PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and great
er in Unknown on line 0

Deprecated: Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in
 Unknown on line 0

Yii Migration Tool v1.0 (based on Yii v1.1.13)

Total 1 new migration to be applied:
    m130703_085302_create_issue_user_and_assignment_tables

Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:yes
*** applying m130703_085302_create_issue_user_and_assignment_tables
*** applied m130703_085302_create_issue_user_and_assignment_tables (time: 0.042s
)


Migrated up successfully.
```

now the problem is that tables are not created in the database it may be because of the msg that register_globals is deprecated but I am not sure what to do, connection parameters are correct and a record was inserted in the table tbl_migration

```
m130703_085302_create_issue_user_and_assignment_ta...   1372842220
```

but no new tables are created.

Answer (score 3):

Creating table usually don't require transactions

```
<?php
class m130630_124600_some_description_name extends CDbMigration
{
    public function up(){
        //upcode example create the session table
        $this->createTable('session',[
             'id' => "varchar(40) NOT NULL",
             'expire' => "int(12)",
             'data' => "blob",
        ]);
        $this->addPrimaryKey('idx','session','id');
    }
    public function down(){
       // downcode (undo the up code) example: drop session table
       $this->dropTable('session');
    }
}
```

---

**If transaction is required**

follows the comment of *safeUp*:

> This method contains the logic to be executed when applying this
>   migration.      This method differs from **up()** in that the DB logic
>   implemented here will       be enclosed within a DB transaction.    Child
>   classes may implement this method instead of **up()** if the DB logic
>       needs to be within a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Check the config/console.php file
Change the dbname, the username and password.
This is the file that the yiic command uses, not config/main.php
It should work now

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are doing the mistake, What i did. yiic is a console command. Check your db properties for console.php in config folder for your project. check your configs for console.

It might be pointing to testdrive.db SQLite default one & the table is created their.

Atleast this was my problem.

Regards, Ajeet

Answer (score 0):

I just dry ran you code in it created the tables alright so I have to assume it's something wrong with what your calling. Only thing that immediatly sticks out is that your running a bash script rather than the bat script.

**yiic** is a bash script. On Windows it is recommended to run **yiic.bat** or **yiic.php**.

Can you run php from the command line? If so:

- Delete the migration from the tbl_migrations
- Run the migrations as "C:\path\to\php.exe yiic.php migrate up"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't created the `tbl_user` or `tbl_issue` tables manually via MySQL. If they exist already, drop them and then run your migration again.

Also check to make sure your database connection strings in `main/config.php` AND `main/console.php` are set up to correctly reference the database the migration should use.

To confirm that it worked, when your migration actually succeeds, you'll get results very similar to the following, listing each SQL action taken. If you don't see any actions taken in the list, it didn't run correctly.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\yii\trackstar\protected>yiic migrate

Yii Migration Tool v1.0 (based on Yii v1.1.14)

Total 1 new migration to be applied:
    m140406_014347_create_user_issue_assignment_tables

Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:y
*** applying m140406_014347_create_user_issue_assignment_tables
    > create table tbl_issue ... done (time: 0.351s)
    > create table tbl_user ... done (time: 0.405s)
    > create table tbl_project_user_assignment ... done (time: 0.366s)
    > add foreign key fk_issue_project: tbl_issue (project_id) references tbl_pr
oject (id) ... done (time: 0.923s)
    > add foreign key fk_issue_owner: tbl_issue (owner_id) references tbl_user (
id) ... done (time: 1.066s)
    > add foreign key fk_issue_requester: tbl_issue (requester_id) references tb
l_user (id) ... done (time: 1.829s)
    > add foreign key fk_project_user: tbl_project_user_assignment (project_id)
references tbl_project (id) ... done (time: 1.416s)
    > add foreign key fk_user_project: tbl_project_user_assignment (user_id) ref
erences tbl_user (id) ... done (time: 1.032s)
*** applied m140406_014347_create_user_issue_assignment_tables (time: 7.446s)


Migrated up successfully.
```

Finally, creation of tables in MySQL will implicitly commit after they're run, so running your code in the `safeDown()` and `safeUp()` methods, which will run your code as MySQL transactions, isn't especially useful. For simplicity, I would move the code in each safe method to the respective "non-safe" method.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are doing the mistake, What i did. yiic is a console command. Check your db properties for console.php in config folder for your project.

It might be pointing to testdrive.db SQLite default one & the table is created their.

Atleast this was my problem.

Regards,
Ajeet

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. This got resolved by moving the code to

public function up()
{
  code here
}

and executing the migration by the following command

shell> yiic migrate up